# How to calculate this improper integral: $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\theta}e^{\cos\theta}\sin(\sin\theta){d\theta}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

Calculate the improper integral
$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\theta}e^{\cos\theta}\sin(\sin\theta){d\theta}}$$
My try:

We know that for any $a\in\mathbb{C}$ the integral
$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$
Let $a=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ we know $$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}{e^{x^2\cos\theta}\sin(x^2\sin\theta){dx}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$$
then $$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\theta}e^{x^2\cos\theta}\sin(x^2\sin\theta){dx}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{\theta}$$
$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}d\theta\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\theta}e^{x^2\cos\theta}\sin(x^2\sin\theta){dx}}=\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{\theta}d\theta$$

Let $F(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\theta}e^{x^2\cos\theta}\sin(x^2\sin\theta){d\theta}}$, then the result equals to $F(1)$,But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You do not know that for any $a\in\Bbb C$. Try $a=-1$; the integral diverges! Moreover, I am unsure how you let $a=\cos+i\sin$ to obtain your result

Comment: Sorry, I forget to say that $Re(a)>0$

Comment: Maybe my try is not a good way, you can prove it in other ways.

Comment: Where did you find this integral? It is not at all trivial. I attempted it using contour integration but the problem appeared intractable

Comment: Experimentally, the answer appears to be $e$, or ever so slightly less than $e$. I do not yet have any idea why

Comment: I know this integral from my professor. He said this integral could be calculated and let me think about it. I tried to use contour integration but I failed. $\frac{1}{\theta}$ seems to be intractable.

Comment: It is the imaginary part of an enticing integral: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)}{\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$But I could go no further

Comment: $\theta=x$?I have tried this one but I don't know the next step.

Comment: Apologies it was a typo. Edited. It results in an infinite sums of contour integrals, of which all are zero except for one which diverges ... so complex analysis isn’t necessarily helpful. Perhaps Feynman integration will help you. I upvoted but I don’t know how to help further

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1<sup>st</sup> Solution.** Define the sine integral by

$$ \operatorname{Si}(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sin t}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t. $$

Using integartion by parts, it can be proved that

$$ \operatorname{Si}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \qquad\text{as } x \to \infty. $$

Now note that $e^{\cos\theta}\sin\sin\theta = \operatorname{Im}(e^{e^{i\theta}}-1) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\sin(n\theta)$. Then by the Fubini's theorem, for $R > 0$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{R} \frac{e^{\cos\theta}\sin\sin\theta}{\theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta
&= \int_{0}^{R} \frac{1}{\theta} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n!} \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \int_{0}^{R} \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \operatorname{Si}(nR) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{nR} \right) \right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}(e - 1) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{R}\right).
\end{align*}

So by letting $R \to \infty$, the integral converges to

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos\theta}\sin\sin\theta}{\theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}(e-1). $$

---

**2<sup>nd</sup> Solution.** It is well-known that

$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k=-N}^{N} \frac{1}{z + 2\pi k} = \frac{1}{2}\cot\left(\frac{z}{2}\right). $$

Moreover, this convergence is locally uniform (in the sense that the difference between the limit and the $N$-th partial sum, when understood as a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, converges to $0$ uniformly on any compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$).

Using this and noting that $e^{\cos\theta}\sin\sin\theta = \operatorname{Im}(e^{e^{i\theta}} - e)$, we find

\begin{align*}
\int_{-(2N+1)\pi}^{(2N+1)\pi} \frac{e^{\cos\theta}\sin\sin\theta}{\theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta
&= \operatorname{Im}\biggl( \int_{-(2N+1)\pi}^{(2N+1)\pi} \frac{e^{e^{i\theta}} - e}{\theta}  \, \mathrm{d}\theta \biggr) \\
&= \operatorname{Im}\biggl( \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (e^{e^{i\theta}} - e) \sum_{k=-N}^{N} \frac{1}{\theta + 2\pi k}  \, \mathrm{d}\theta \biggr) \\
&\to \operatorname{Im}\biggl( \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (e^{e^{i\theta}} - e) \frac{1}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)  \, \mathrm{d}\theta \biggr)
\qquad\text{as } N \to \infty.
\end{align*}

Now we substitute $z = e^{i\theta}$. Then using the identity $\cot(\theta/2) = i \frac{e^{i\theta} + 1}{e^{i\theta} - 1}$ and the residue theorem,

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos\theta}\sin\sin\theta}{\theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta
&= \operatorname{Im}\biggl( \frac{1}{2} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{(e^{z} - e)(z+1)}{z(z-1)} \, \mathrm{d}z \biggr) \\
&= \operatorname{Im}\biggl( \pi i \, \underset{z=0}{\operatorname{Res}} \frac{(e^{z} - e)(z+1)}{z(z-1)}  \biggr) \\
&= \pi(e - 1).
\end{align*}

Dividing both sides by $2$, we conclude that

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos\theta}\sin\sin\theta}{\theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}(e - 1). $$

Comment: @FShrike, There is no mistake in your reasoning, since $\operatorname{Im}(-1) = 0$. I introduced that extra term to emphasize that the zero-th term (corresponding to $n=0$) in the series expansion vanishes.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I retracted my comment as soon as I realised your point! This is a good answer

Comment: $\newcommand{\si}{\mathrm{Si}}\newcommand{\o}{\mathcal{O}}\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$$$\si(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$Because: $$\si(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\d t-\int_x^\infty\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\d t=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x}\left(\cos(x)-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-\cdots\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$Right?

Comment: @FShrike. That is correct. However, you do not need the full power of that identity. By integration by parts, $$ \int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\left[-\frac{\cos t}{t}\right]_{x}^{\infty}-\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t $$ and it is easy to check that this is $\mathcal{O}(x^{-1})$.

Comment: Your cotangent sum at the start of the second solution; this smacks of a Laurent series, or perhaps a residue thm + contour integral. I’d like to try it for myself as an exercise; what’s the contour used?

Comment: @FShrike, One way of proving that identity is to check that the difference of both sides defines a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ that is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

It’s $\pi(e-1)/2$ which is around $2.7$ - surprisingly close to $e$.  If you Taylor expand $e^{e^{ix}}$, the $n$th term is $e^{inx}/n!$. Integrating $\sin(nx)/x$ over positive reals for positive $n$ is $\pi/2$, but $0$ when $n$ is 0. This gives the imiginary part of the integrated infinite series as the sum of $\pi/2$ times the sum of $1/n!$ over all positive $n$ which is $e-1$.

Comment: You're right, but you may want to put more detail in your answer, as Sangchul did

Comment: Agreed - op should just mark his as the best solution.